# Generate server.go base on grpc proto method with GoLand

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

Are there some functional or plugin in GoLand to generate `server/server.go`  method base on proto rpc method?

for example we have `some.proto`:

```
...
rpc AnyMetod (AnyRequest) return (AnyResponse)
...
```

and I want to have generated:

```
func (s *Server) AnyMethod(ctx context.Context, req *AnyRequest) (*AnyResponse, error) {
    return &AnyResponse{}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment I don't know of any such plugin or functionality available.

If you want to develop your own plugin, you can start by reading our [SDK documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html).

As an alternative, I think you can use the [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/settings-live-templates.html) feature in order to achieve something very similar to that, with the content along the lines of the example below and define the template to be available for "Go | File" context:

```
func (s *$VAR4$) $VAR0$(ctx context.Context, req *$VAR1$) (*$VAR2$, error) {
    return &$VAR2${}
}
```

Comment: many thanks for info you provided: live template works fine for now. I thought about plugin before - now I know how to start :)